# Openlayers: Load coordinate-data from request

Tags: openlayers

I'd like to load Coordinate-Data from a http-request and draw it as a linestring.

So far I have:

```
var coordinates = [[30.433333,19.066667], [30.732778,19.704444],[30.832778,19.84444]]; 
var featurestreet=new ol.Feature({
   geometry: new ol.geom.LineString(coordinates),
   name: 'xyz'
});
```

But now I want to load the vector-data from a file like this:

```
var stree = new ol.layer.Vector({
    source: new ol.source.Vector(
{
    url: 'points.txt',
        format: new ol.format.GPX(), //what format to use here?
        name:'stree'
    })

  }); 
map.addLayer(stree);
```

What is the correct format? I want to keep it very simple and compressed, so I dont't want to use any blown up xml-code in this data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's probably best done by wrapping the coordinates as a GeoJSON:

```
{ "type": "FeatureCollection", "features": [ { "type": "Feature", "geometry": { "type": "LineString", "coordinates":
[[30.433333,19.066667], [30.732778,19.704444],[30.832778,19.84444]]
} } ] }
```

If your .txt files simply contained the coordinates array you could use a custom loader as in http://openlayers.org/en/v4.6.5/apidoc/ol.source.Vector.html and add the GeoJSON header and footer strings to xhr.responseText in vectorSource.getFormat().readFeatures()

To include the name in the GeoJSON:

```
{ "type": "FeatureCollection", "features": [ { "type": "Feature", "properties": { "name": "xyz" }, "geometry": { "type": "LineString", "coordinates":
[[30.433333,19.066667], [30.732778,19.704444],[30.832778,19.84444]]
} } ] }
```